# How to make a thread finish its job when i close the app

Tags: java, android

In my Android app, I need to update the database with the timestamp indicating when the user closes the app. I am using a separate thread to achieve this but it seems like the app does not wait for the thread to finish and terminates it.

```
    private void endSession() {
        try {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

            AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "circles").build();
            SessionDAO userSessionDao = db.sessionDAO();
            new Thread(() -> {
                userSessionDao.updateSessionEndTime(endTime);
                latch.countDown();
            }).start();
            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("MyTag", "Session end failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

In my code above you can see that i used the method CountDownLatch but it did not work.

EDIT.
I am calling the endSession() from my onDestroy() of the MainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        endSession();
    }
```

My definition of "closing the app" is opening my devices app switcher to swipe and close the app or pressing "Stop 'app'" from the android studio.
Since this method is run on my onDestroy() i had to close the app to test it and noticed that the database was not updated (i tested the function endSession() separately and it worked normally on a button click listener).

Comment: "when the user closes the app" -- what is your specific definition of "closes the app"? "but it seems like the app does not wait for the thread to finish and terminates it" -- what is causing this method to be executed? How are you determining what this thread is or is not doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  Force stopping or swiping away from the task switcher kill the process immediately.  That means all threads end exactly where they are.  There is no chance to process it.  It's like alt-ctrl-delete on windows.  Both are abnormal terminations.

Also, onDestroy of MainActivity would be wrong anyway.  There can be more than one instance of MainActivity and onDestroy could be called on one of them.  To see this, just rotate the phone.  And just because your activity is destroyed does not mean the app, or any of its threads, are terminated.  It just means the OS is no longer keeping an instance of your activity in memory.  It regularly cleans out backgrounded activities like that.

Also, the idea of being told when an app is terminated is kind of broken anyway.  Imaging the phone's battery is removed.  Your app would be immediately terminated, because the phone itself is no longer running.  There really is no way to detect when that happened.  The only way I could really think to approach it would be to constantly write the current time to disk.  Then the next time you launch the app, you know the time it previously stopped based on the last time that successfully wrote.